# Add causing php-script to mysql-slow.log

Tags: mysql, php, logging, debugging

If you enable the line

```
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

in

```
/etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

then that will log all queries, that take longer than the setting in `long_query_time`.

On a server with many websites hosted you'll get entries, that show, which host caused which time in the form like:

```
# Time: 130508  0:04:07
# User@Host: dbuser[dbhost] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 9.354343  Lock_time: 0.000094 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use database_name;
SET timestamp=1367964247;
UPDATE some_table SET something='some data'
```

but the most important information is missing: **which script called that query?** And multiple slow queries inside the same script don't add up in time, so it would be handsome to have an analysis, that finds out the script-name automatically.

Is it possible to add the PHP-script name to that log?

Or maybe somehow combine the different logs somehow in an analysis script, that finds out, which script was called during that time the slow query was called?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way for MySQL to know what PHP script was running. All it knows is it got a connection from username, password, host, and was asked for some query. So it logs what it has available.

If you're the developer, you should hopefully be familiar enough with your application to locate the code making the query within a few seconds. If you aren't the developer, or aren't familiar with the application, try `grep`. Or contact the developer who is familiar with it.

Comment: On a server with 250 hosts you cannot be familiar with all scripts

Comment: You have the username! So you know whose script it is.

Comment: Sure, I could find out for each entry with some work, but I need a solution to analyse all slow queries and find out the worst scripts to contact only that customer. besides: multiple slow queries inside the same script don't add up in time.

Comment: A simple shell script could tell you which users are logging the most slow queries. Do you have a system administrator? If not, you probably should hire one.

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't like the answer, but the pointless downvote was just rude.

Comment: @rubo77 - If each customer is using a unique username, or in the case of cpanel-like systems, a unique prefix on their username, it should be trivial to locate the customer. After that, the onus is on them to fix their scripts.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't want to be rude, but this discussion doesen't lead to a solution. I am not trying to find out a single problem, but I would like to have a kind of warning-system, that shows globally upcoming problems on my server in a log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a comment to your queries and this will do the job:

```
SELECT * FROM table # php file ./path/to/file.php
```

Comment: this is a nice Idea, but it will only help to some scripts, that you created yourself. Here I search for a solution to find out which of my 250 domains on the server causes the problem in the slow-log

Comment: @rubo77 if you are using any query builder it should be quite easy to add this comment for all the queries. Also Yii2 solves this issue in another way: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/Command.php#L1091